# Функция выдает ошибку SuspiciousFileOperation

Tags: python, django

В Django-проекте есть функция:

```
    def create_docs(medic_id: str, context: dict, type_in: str) -> str:
        if type_in == 'zayavlenie':
            template = f'{BASE_DIR}/static/templates_docs/shablon_zayavleniya.docx'
        elif type_in == 'portfolio':
            template = f'{BASE_DIR}/static/templates_docs/shablon_portfolio.docx'
        elif type_in == 'otchet':
            template = f'{BASE_DIR}/static/templates_docs/shablon_otcheta.docx'
        elif type_in == 'pamyatka':
            template = f'{BASE_DIR}/static/templates_docs/shablon_pamyatky.docx'
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Некорректное значение type_in: {type_in}')
        doc = DocxTemplate(template)
        doc.render(context)
        file_name = f"{BASE_DIR}/docs/{type_in}.docx"
        doc.save(file_name)
        medic = get_object_or_404(Medic, id=medic_id)
        if type_in == 'zayavlenie':
            with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
                medic.statement.save(file_name, File(f))
        if type_in == 'portfolio':
            with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
                medic.portfolio.save(file_name, File(f))
        if type_in == 'otchet':
            with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
                medic.report.save(file_name, File(f))
        if type_in == 'pamyatka':
            with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
                medic.readme.save(file_name, File(f))
        return
```

Функция принимает 4 docx шаблона, и словарь `context` . На выходе формирует 4 файла с подставленными данными из словаря, плюс формирует ссылку и прикрепляет ее к полю модели, которые заданы следующим образом:

```
    class Medic(models.Model):
        statement = models.FileField(blank=True)
        portfolio = models.FileField(blank=True)
        report = models.FileField(blank=True)
        readme = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

Я не до конца понимаю как работает эта функция, собрал этот компот по ответам из интернета. На локальном компьютере она сделает так (на примере одного файла из 4-х):
Обращение 1-го пользователя:

1. Формирует файл `otchet.docx`
2. Формирует файл `otchet_0uUIBFc.docx`
3. Записывает ссылку на `otchet_0uUIBFc.docx` в поле `medic.report`

Обращение 2-го пользователя:

1. Перезаписывает файл `otchet.docx`
2. Формирует файл otchet_CT52ndN.docx
3. Записывает ссылку на `otchet_CT52ndN.docx` в поле `medic.report`
   И так далее.

Сейчас я переношу проект на хостинг, и на хостинге джанго категорически ругается на эту функцию. Ошибка такая:
SuspiciousFileOperation at /form/done/
Detected path traversal attempt in '/home/c/cz33441/med_site/public_html/accreditation/docs/otchet.docx'
И я совсем не понимаю в чем может быть дело.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста как устранить эту ошибку, либо как лучше реализовать эту функцию. Очевидно, что решение так себе, но ничего лучше не могу придумать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744024/8324991) на английском СО. Если вкратце, то не нужно писать ничего в те каталоги, где лежит сайт, это опасная практика по многим причинам, поэтому `Django` и ругается. Писать можно во **временные файлы**, расположенные в специально отведённых для временных файлов местах. Для этого в `Django` есть специальные методы.